# how to three select menu handle in angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs, select

I need help to
Three selected DropDown menu 
when one select menu value after second select menu open and when second select value after third select menu open in angularjs.I have Create Fiddle ,
But i have one problem i have data is in array whenever i pass data that time show in string.

Fiddle link in comment..

Comment: can you elaborate Scenario with some realistic scenario or code updation ??

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ZwwH7/4/

Comment: So you want to select  only first one then the other 2 menus auto select same the option that is what you are trying to do is correct ?

Comment: can you have any example @N.V.Prasad

Comment: Iam not clear on what you need actually .. i want a real time scenario with some sample data which makes sense ..

Comment: i need this type value example                                                        [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ZwwH7/13/)                                                   but i pass array value in county and state list-@N.V.Prasad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this fiddle,It will help you.

```
https://jsfiddle.net/annavester/Zd6uX/
```

```js
function AjaxCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.countries = ['usa', 'canada', 'mexico', 'france'];
    $scope.$watch('country', function(newVal) {
        if (newVal) $scope.cities = ['Los Angeles', 'San Francisco'];
    });
    $scope.$watch('city', function(newVal) {
        if (newVal) $scope.suburbs = ['SOMA', 'Richmond', 'Sunset'];
    });
}

function StaticCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.countries = {
        'usa': {
            'San Francisco': ['SOMA', 'Richmond', 'Sunset'],
            'Los Angeles': ['Burbank', 'Hollywood']
        },
        'canada': {
            'People dont live here': ['igloo', 'cave']
        }
    };
}
```

```html
  <div ng-controller="AjaxCtrl">
      <h1>AJAX - Oriented</h1>
    <div>
        Country: 
        <select id="country" ng-model="country" ng-options="country for country in countries">
          <option value=''>Select</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div>
        City: <select id="city" ng-disabled="!cities" ng-model="city" ng-options="city for city in cities"><option value=''>Select</option></select>
    </div>
    <div>
        Suburb: <select id="suburb" ng-disabled="!suburbs" ng-model="suburb" ng-options="suburb for suburb in suburbs"><option value=''>Select</option></select>        
    </div>
</div>
  <div ng-controller="StaticCtrl">
      <h1>Static - Oriented</h1>
      <p>This approach may be better when you have the entire dataset</p>
    <div>
        Country: 
        <select id="country" ng-model="cities" ng-options="country for (country, cities) in countries">
          <option value=''>Select</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div>
        City: <select id="city" ng-disabled="!cities" ng-model="suburbs" ng-options="city for (city, suburbs) in cities"><option value=''>Select</option></select>
    </div>
    <div>
        Suburb: <select id="suburb" ng-disabled="!suburbs" ng-model="suburb" ng-options="suburb for suburb in suburbs"><option value=''>Select</option></select>        
    </div>
  </div>
```

Try it.